# Include newlines when counting the number of characters typed into textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I use the following function to return the **number of characters** in a **textarea**:

```
function chunk_string(str, length) {
    return str.match(new RegExp('.{1,' + length + '}', 'g'));
}
```

But it does not count newlines. Is there a way to also include newlines (line breaks) in the character count?

Comment: Care to build a [mcve] to showcase fully your case? Add testcases too.

Comment: Why would you use a function named `chunk_string` to count characters? Why is simply accessing the string _length_ not enough?

Comment: And do you even have any _actual_ line breaks in your content? You might need to chose a different wrapping behavior for your textarea to begin with, before you even get any.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the `length` like so `text.value.length`

```js
length = () => {
  var text = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
  console.log(text.value.length);
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<button onClick="length()">Get length</button>
```

Comment: Be careful of using length in Unicode strings, eg. `''.length` = 2, were as `[...''].length` = 1

Comment: @Keith Isn't "emojis" usually constructed by several characters? so if  = 2 i still think that is correct

Comment: Yes, it's made of 4, and a lot of are made of 2, but the 2 ones come out as 1.  So basically length on Unicode is really not very useful, especially from a human perspective.  Eg. explaining to a user of a system why a smiley counts as 2 characters is not something I'd like to do.. :)  But doing `[...text.value].length` isn't really that hard.

Comment: @Keith Yeah haha that would not be a easy task XD